# Failed log in attempts table

Tags: mysql, forms, security, authentication

So, I am creating a table for failed log in attempts. Should I store the password the person entered as is, or hashed, or not store it at all?

If it is as is, it maybe really similar to the person's actual password, if i store it hashed, what the hell do I want it for? That leaves only the last option. Am I right? Thanks

Any suggestions for this are welcome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why you need the password for? Just store the user's IP , the username to know which username he tried to connect to and the time of the event.

Later since you got the username you can compare with user table if the username and IP is same or similar so you will know if it's user's fault or brute force attemp

Comment: Yes, it was a stupid question :) I should downvote myself

Answer (score 0):

> what the hell do I want it for?

You might be able to better detect patterns of abuse. For example a bot trying the same passwords against different accounts, brute force/dictionary attacks, and attempts to use leaked account information from other sources. You may be able to correlate different attackers better.

Generally this is considered of marginal utility and not at all worth the risk of storing and exposing this information which in the common non-abuse case is indeed likely to be sensitive.